# Pivot table Calculated field - Sumif(s) between two dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I'm attempting to calculate periods of out of stock for a fleet of rental equipment that has been in service for the past few years. I'm having trouble creating a sumif calculated field that sums units by date if date is between start and finish. My data looks like this:

```
Calendar  |Start    |Finish    |Product   |Units
2015-12-06|2015-12-6|2015-12-6 |Snowshoes |2
2015-12-07|2015-12-6|2015-12-7 |Snowshoes |1
```

Calendar - is a helper column I've added. It's sequential dates from launch to the present
Start - is the start Date of a rental booking 
Finish - end date of the rental booking
Product - What's being rented
Units - How many are rented for that booking

I'd like the pivot table to look like:

```
Date       | Snowshoes | Tent ... etc
2015-12-06 | 3         | 
2015-12-07 | 1         |
```

I'm having a hard time setting up calculated field that will sum units if date is between start and finish, I keep getting formula errors.

Here's the formula I'm attempting to use to create a calculated field:

```
= sumifs( Units ,Start,">= Calendar" , Finish,"<= Calendar")
```

Is this even the best way to go about solving this problem? Is my formula the issue or is the entire approach flawed?

Adding screenshots: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 'SUMIFS' or `SUMPRODUCT` is probably the way to go.  But for comparing in `SUMIFS`, you will need to use `">="&Calendar` and `"<="&Calendar` instead.

Comment: Like this?
= SUMPRODUCT(Units,Start,">= &Calendar",Finish,"<= &Calendar")
 - this resulted in #VALUE! in all cells 

= SUMPRODUCT(Units,Start,">= &Calendar",Finish,"<= &Calendar")
- this resulted in formula error

Comment: `=SUMIFS(Units,Start,">="&Calendar,Finish,"<="&Calendar)` or `=SUMPRODUCT(Units,Start>=Calendar,Finish<=Calendar)` if I didn't twist my eyes typing here.  Or try and then post the screenshot here so we can better assist you.

Comment: I'm still having the same issues after moving the quotes to the correct position. Not sure sure what you'd want to see in the screenshot, but I'm happy to take one.

Comment: added some screenshots that I thought might help

Answer (score 0):

From the data you have in the screenshots, this is what I came up.

[image]

The formula to use in `column G`:

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$29,$A$2:$A$29,"<="&F2,$B$2:$B$29,">="&$F2)
```

The formula to use in `column H` (BTW, this is just for your reference.  You can use either one of them):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$29<=F2),--($B$2:$B$29>=F2),$E$2:$E$29)
```

From here, I created a `Pivot Table` like this:

[image]

Hopefully this can help you.  But definitely let me know if I miss anything from your question.

Comment: So those formulas worked to create the data that goes into the pivot table, but something breaks down in the table. I'm getting numbers that are way off for the individual products, even though the daily totals are accurate. 

It actually looks like you're having the same issue in the screenshot that you sent met. for 12/12, your table shows 22 rentals for "black Diamond", but the data I sent you doesn't support that 

I also discovered that I might have been having trouble because I'd been using Excel for Mac. Once I switched to windows the formulas you supplied worked fine.

Comment: The data from `column A to column F` on my example is hard-coded as the exact sample you provided.  For 12/22/2015 Calendar, it is the sum of `cell E13 to E29` in the number of 22 if I understand your intention correctly.  But correct me if I am missing your point.